# how to get success on jquery ajax request?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http, web

im new to ajax but i dont undersend the error
i have this code:

```
function text_ajax(){
  $('.purchase-btn').click(function() {
    var JSONObject= {
      "prod_name":          $('.soc-name span').text(),
      "prod_quantity":      $('.soc-amount span').text(), 
      "prod_price":         $('.soc-price span').text(),
      "prod_line_price":    $('.soc-total span').text(),
      "prod_shipment_price":$('.soc-shipping-fee span').text(),
      "prod_vat":           $('.soc-vat-fee span').text(),
      "prod_total_price":   $('.soc-total-sum').text(),
      };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "/soda/checkout/ajax_post",
        data: {myData: JSON.stringify(JSONObject)},
        success: function(){
            alert('Items added');
        },
        error: function(e){
            alert(e.message);
        }
    });

  });
}
```

and i get all the elements but stil getting an error 
can somone help?

Comment: you have an unnecessary comma here `$('.soc-total-sum').text(),` <--

Comment: do you really want to pass all your data as a string? because you can just do `data:JSONObject,` inside your ajax call... Also - why are you binding the click event hander inside a function?

Comment: *"but i dont undersend the error"* what error? my guess is your server isn't returning valid json.

Answer (score 4):

First, I would move the click event handler to call the function it is contained within.

Secondly, as ᾠῗᵲᄐᶌ stated there is an uncessary comma and the data does not need to be stringifed.

```
$('body').on('click', '.purchase-btn', function() {   
    var JSONObject= {
      "prod_name":          $('.soc-name span').text(),
      "prod_quantity":      $('.soc-amount span').text(), 
      "prod_price":         $('.soc-price span').text(),
      "prod_line_price":    $('.soc-total span').text(),
      "prod_shipment_price":$('.soc-shipping-fee span').text(),
      "prod_vat":           $('.soc-vat-fee span').text(),
      "prod_total_price":   $('.soc-total-sum').text()
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "/soda/checkout/ajax_post",
        data: JSONObject,
        success: function(){
            alert('Items added');
        },
        error: function(e){
            alert(e.message);
        }
    });

});
```

Please post the actual error message if there is one after using this modified code.